# Как через форму передать данные в firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Как можно закинуть данные в Realtime Database firebase через форму.
То бишь, есть на странице товары, данные для этих товаров подгружаются с firebase, есть форма для добавления новой карточки, когда её добавляю она появляется на странице, но при перезагрузке она пропадает.
Как данные эти можно закинуть в Realtime Database firebase, чтобы при добавлении товара, она сразу появлялась в базе данных.

Comment: после в обработчике формы делать запрос к firebase на добавление данных